# Dynamic programming - mobile

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have to apply dynamic programming on this problem, but I am not really sure how.

There are 50 buttons with 2000 letters on the mobile phone (sorted alphabetically). Each letter has k-position at the button (letter is typed by k presses). Then we know, how much is the letter used. Program will determine, on which button the letter should be positioned in order to find out minimum number of presses.

Input:

number of buttons

number of letters

frequency of each character in average letter.
Example:

```
3 // number of buttons

5 // number of letters

1 // frequency of first letter

1 // frequency of second letter

1 // frequency of third letter

1 // frequency of fourth letter

1 // frequency of fifth letter
```

Solution:

Buttons: 1 2 | 3 4 | 5

1 * 1 + 2 * 1 = 3

1 * 1 + 2 * 1 = 3

1 * 1 = 1
Output is: 3 + 3 + 1 = 7

Program will output: 7

I have made solution to this example. I've created two matrices. One has S*S dimension and the other one has K*S dimension. In S*S matrix each element represent price of the button, which has characters from i coordinate to j coordinate. In K*S matrix i represents number of buttons and j represents characters to j.

I have a problem, how to find buttons with minimul cost.

For example:

I want to find in K*S table value in [2,3] coordinate. It means, we are spliting three characters in to two buttons. Optimal solution is, that one button will have 2 characters and other one will have one character. In S*S solution would be [1,1] + [2,3] or [1,2] + [3,3].

I will appreciate every advice.

table S*S

```
1 3 6 10 15

0 1 3 6 10

0 0 1 3 6

0 0 0 1 3

0 0 0 0 1
```

table K*S

```
1 3 6 10 15

0 2 4 6 9

0 0 3 5 7
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is: You are given buttons, letters, and frequency, and you want to find the optimal position to place the letters such that you achieve the smallest "output"?
If yes, then you can sort the letters by frequency and distribute them one by one to subsequent buttons such that you achieve an even distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant

Answer (score 1):

You may be familiar with the reasoning behind a Huffman Code, where for optimal usage, or highest efficiency, the least amount of work should be done to get the highest frequency letters. This logic holds for your problem as well. You want to perform the least amount of button presses to reach the highest frequency letters.

Let's say we have `numB buttons` and `numL letters`. Let's also assume we have an object called Letter with `char letter`, and `int frequency` attributes, and finally, we have `LetterCol` which is a collection of Letter objects. (My c# is rusty, bear with me).

Step 1:
Sort these letters by frequency.(Any sort function will work). We will use a collection of arraylists of Letters `Keypad`. It will function like a map.

Each position in `Keypad` will be an arraylist. Each position will relate to one button. `Keypad[0]` relates to `button 0`. `Keypad[0]` is also an ArrayList of letters. This will be populated with the letters we wish to place on `button 0`.

```
List<ArrayList<Letter>> Keypad = new ArrayList<>();
```

Step 2:
Since `LetterCol` is sorted by frequency, we just place each letter sequentially on `Keypad`. We will use the `mod` function `%` to ensure we stay within our bounds (i.e., we don't exceed the number of buttons `numB`).

```
for(int i = 0; i < numL; i++)
   Keypad[i%numB].add(LetterCol[i]);
```

Now, our placement process is complete. Each letter is placed in it's optimal position. It is time to calculate the output.

Step 3:
We now need to access each position in `Keypad` and retrieve each letter in those ArrayLists.

```
int output = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numB; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < Keypad[i].count; j++){
      output += (j+1)*(Keypad[i][j].frequency);
```

//My syntax may be incorrect, in Java it is: output += (j+1)*(Keypad[i].get[j].frequency);

Now we contain the optimal `output`. In your numbers example, you go to each button and multiply the number of presses to the frequency of the letter. These for loops perform the same calculation. We go to each button `i`, multiply the number of presses `j+1` to the frequency of the letter `Keypad[i][j].frequency`.